# What Keys to be made while storing news data in dynamo db?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I need some guidance regarding how to store News Records in Dynamo DB

```
{
    "news": [{
        "id": "nws_7KnqNr",
        "title": "Dow Jones Futures: From Apple To Zscaler, This Is The New Stock Market Trend",
        "publication_date": "2019-09-11T10:46:24.000Z",
        "url": "https://finance.yahoo.com/m/c5f84bed-ce61-3938-9af1-953d15dbcf65/dow-jones-futures%3A-from-apple.html?.tsrc=rss",
        "summary": "Dow Jones futures: From low Apple TV+ pricing to Roku's sell-off and Ally Financial's breakout, value is in. Already-reeling Zscaler plunged on guidance. RH fell too."
    }],
    "company": {
        "id": "com_NX6GzO",
        "ticker": "AAPL",
        "name": "Apple Inc",
        "lei": "HWUPKR0MPOU8FGXBT394",
        "cik": "0000320193"
    },
    "next_page": "MjAxOS0wOS0xMSAxMDo0NjoyNCBVVEN8NTM1NDYzNg=="
}
```

This is sample JSON

News is being pulled from some API and should be stored in Dynamo DB

What keys needs to be made for efficient retrival?
News can be fetched as per company too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
News
----------
id (hash key)
title
publication_date
url 
summary
company_id (index - hash key)
```

Should do the trick. So every element of the "news" array will go here, with the company id. If you want to fetch by news id, you can do it efficiently and also by company id (because of the index).

There will be issues with the index if there are several big companies which will have most news (Apple for example) and you have a lot of data.

In order to fix that, use

```
company_by_month_id (index - hash key)
```

which is a compound key.

**Update:**

```
company_name (index - hash key + timestamp as sort key)
ticker (index - hash key + timestamp as sort key)
timestamp (this is generated)
```

Query the two indexes created to get the most recent news items based on company name or ticker.

Comment: Thanks Horatiu Jeflea for your response.
As there will be no filter for news based on news parameters except Company Name or Ticker, so can I make them Sort Key only

Comment: what querying do you need more exactly? to fetch all news ticker and fetch all news by company name?

Comment: As per requirement the news needs to be fetched by company ticker or name